# Option -l of exec shell command

Tags: linux, shell, command

Could you please clarify on the use of `-l` option of `exec` shell command. I didn't notice any difference when I ran `exec ls | cat` and `exec -l ls | cat`.

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html

Comment: Thanks!. Went through that guide. If possible, could you please explain it through an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-l` option of `exec` adds a `-` at the beginning of the name of your command. For example:

```
exec -l diff | head

-diff: missing operand after '-diff'
-diff: Try '-diff --help' for more information.
```

Note the `-` everywhere before `diff`.

The point of all this? If you have a `-` before a command to start a shell it will act as a login shell. From `man bash`:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.

Now, `man exec` states that:

> If the -l option is supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed  to  command.   This  is
>                 what  login(1)  does.

So `exec -l bash` will run `bash` as a login shell. To test this, we can use the fact that a login bash executes the file `~/.bash_profile`, so:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
#!/bin/sh

printf "I am a login shell!\n"
```

If I start a login bash, the command `printf "I am a login shell!\n"` will be executed. Now to test with `exec`:

```
$ exec bash
$
```

Nothing is displayed, we are on a non-login shell.

```
$ exec -l bash
I am a login shell!
$
```

Here we have a login shell.